# Change 'data-val-number' message validation in HTML page

Tags: excel, vba

```html
<select name="UnhedgedYes" id="DDLLUnhedgedYes" style="font-size: 12px;"><option value="Yes">Yes</option>
<option value="No">No</option>
</select>
 <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="UnhedgedYes"></span>




 <select name="DDLIPRUFCE" class="DDLIPRUFCE" id="DDLIPRUFCE" style="font-size: 12px;" data-val-required="Please Select Incremental Provisioning Requirement-due to UFCE" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field DDLIPRUFCE must be a number."><option value="">[Select]</option>
<option value="1" text="0">0</option><option value="6" text="10">10</option>
 <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="DDLIPRUFCE"></span>
 <input name="hidDDLIPRUFCE" id="hidDDLIPRUFCE" type="hidden" value="" autocomplete="off" data-val-required="The hidDDLIPRUFCE field is required." data-val="true" data-val-number="The field hidDDLIPRUFCE must be a number.">




<select name="DDLIRiskW" class="DDLIRiskW" id="DDLIRiskW" style="font-size: 12px;" data-val-required="Please Select Incremental Risk Weight- due to UFCE" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field DDLIRiskW must be a number."><option value="">[Select]</option>
<option value="2" text="0">0</option><option value="1" text="25">25</option></select>
                                            
 <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="DDLIRiskW"></span>
 <input name="hidDDLIRiskW" id="hidDDLIRiskW" type="hidden" value="" autocomplete="off" data-val-required="The hidDDLIRiskW field is required." data-val="true" data-val-number="The field hidDDLIRiskW must be a number.">
```

I have two three dropdowns in webpage. Manually On selecting the first dropdown as "No" the other two automatically show zero in it. On hitting enter it moves to next html page.
However I am able to select values in all the three dropdowns using vba but on hitting enter the two dropdowns again show "Select" instead of 0 and does not move to the next page.

I tried `For each` loop as well as `getElementByID`

```
Set Post = ie.document.getElementById("DDLLUnhedgedYes")
''I din't use any index to do the job
For Each elem In Post.getElementsByTagName("option")
    If InStr(elem.Value, "No") > 0 Then
        elem.Selected = True            
        Exit For
    End If
Next elem

ie.document.getElementById("DDLIPRUFCE").getElementsByTagName("option")(1).Selected = True: ie.document.getElementById("DDLIPRUFCE").FireEvent ("onchange")
ie.document.getElementById("DDLIRiskW").getElementsByTagName("option")(1).Selected = True: ie.document.getElementById("DDLIRiskW").FireEvent ("onchange")

ie.document.getElementById("btnEnter").Click
```

on hitting Enter the webpages should move to another page.

Comment: Can you share the url? At the very least therelevant html using the snippet tool available via [edit]. Also, can you remove your loop and simply say ie.document.querySelector("option[value=No]").Selected = True

Comment: The url will not be accessible outside the organisation.

Comment: Can you include enough html for us to understand the problem?

Comment: Hi Sunny, thanks for adding html. You need to use the [edit] functionality to add that code, properly formatted into your question using the snippet tool. The snippet tool is the icon that looks like a document with <> on it. You can also use pastebin.com to share links of code.

Comment: Hi QHarr..thnx for ur support. I hve added html snippet for ur reference